# SSE _mm_load_ps causing segmentation faults

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sse, intrinsics

So I have been having trouble with this toy example for learning to program with SSE intrinsics. I read on other threads here that sometimes segmentation faults with the _mm_load_ps function are caused by not aligning things right but I think it should be solved by the **attribute**((**aligned**(16))) thing that I did. Also, when I comment out either line 23 or 24 (or both) in my code the problem goes away but obviously this makes the code not work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        float temp1[] __attribute__((__aligned__(16))) = {1.1,1.2,1.3,14.5,3.1,5.2,2.3,3.4};
        float temp2[] __attribute__((__aligned__(16))) = {1.2,2.3,3.4,3.5,1.2,2.3,4.2,2.2};
        float temp3[8];
        __m128 m, *m_result;
        __m128 arr1 = _mm_load_ps(temp1);
        __m128 arr2 = _mm_load_ps(temp2);

        m = _mm_mul_ps(arr1, arr2);
        *m_result = _mm_add_ps(m, m); 
        _mm_store_ps(temp3, *m_result); 
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {   
            cout << temp3[i] << endl;
        }   

        m_result++;
        arr1 = _mm_load_ps(temp1+4);
        arr2 = _mm_load_ps(temp2+4);
        m = _mm_mul_ps(arr1, arr2);
        *m_result = _mm_add_ps(m,m);
        _mm_store_ps(temp3, *m_result); 


        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {   
            cout << temp3[i] << endl;
        }   
        return 0;
}
```

Line 23 is arr1 = _mm_load_ps(temp1+4). It's weird to me that I can do one or the other but not both. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You've aligned temp1 to 16 bytes but then added 4 to it pretty much ensuring that it is NOT 16 byte aligned...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow, don't I have to use _mm_load_ps(temp1+4) to  load in the next 4 values?

Comment: @jcoder: +4 (floats) is +16 bytes, so the loads are OK - it's the two stores that are the problem here.

Comment: ...and the dangling pointer of course.

Comment: @PaulR absolutely. Please disregard my comment... I shoudn't comment until I've had at least 2 cups of coffee! My apologies for the wrong comment.

Comment: Heh - we've all been there...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you declare a pointer `__m128 *m_result` but you never allocate any space for it.  Later you also do `m_result++` which points to another memory address which has not been allocate.  There is no reason to use a pointer here.

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>                 // SSE
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        float temp1[] __attribute__((__aligned__(16))) = {1.1,1.2,1.3,14.5,3.1,5.2,2.3,3.4};
        float temp2[] __attribute__((__aligned__(16))) = {1.2,2.3,3.4,3.5,1.2,2.3,4.2,2.2};
        float temp3[8];
        __m128 m, m_result;
        __m128 arr1 = _mm_load_ps(temp1);
        __m128 arr2 = _mm_load_ps(temp2);

        m = _mm_mul_ps(arr1, arr2);
        m_result = _mm_add_ps(m, m); 
        _mm_store_ps(temp3, m_result); 
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {   
            cout << temp3[i] << endl;
        }   

        arr1 = _mm_load_ps(temp1+4);
        arr2 = _mm_load_ps(temp2+4);
        m = _mm_mul_ps(arr1, arr2);
        m_result = _mm_add_ps(m,m);
        _mm_store_ps(temp3, m_result); 


        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {   
            cout << temp3[i] << endl;
        }   
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note also that `temp3` is potentially misaligned.

Comment: Good point.  I just tried the code and it worked.  That's probably because it was compiled in 64-bit mode which alignes variables on the stack to 16 bytes.

Comment: Yes, compiling for 64 bits can be both a blessing and a curse. Note also that you do not need SSE4.1 here - there's nothing beyond SSE2 in the code above.

Comment: Right again. I though he said he used `_mm_dp_ps` but I don't see that now.

Comment: @PaulR, actually, there is nothing beyond SSE here.  Not even SSE2 is needed.

Comment: Hey this is exactly what I was looking for, so I basically used the code from above and added 'float temp3[8] __attribute__((__aligned__(16)));' and it worked perfect, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

(1) `m_result` is just a [wild pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_pointer):

```
     __m128 m, *m_result;
```

Change all occurrences of `*m_result` to `m_result` and get rid of the `m_result++;`. (`m_result` is just a temporary vector variable that you are subsequently storing to `temp3`).

(2) Your two stores are potentially misaligned, since `temp3` has no guaranteed alignment - either change:

```
    float temp3[8];
```

to:

```
    float temp3[8] __attribute__((__aligned__(16)));
```

or use `_mm_storeu_ps`:

```
    _mm_storeu_ps(temp3, m_result); 
            ^^^
```

Comment: +1 Since your answer is a bit better than mine.  Though I think the proper term here is a wild pointer not a dangling pointer.  Wild pointers are pointers that have not been initialized to allocated memory and dangling pointers are ones the point to memory that has already been deallocated.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer

Comment: You're right - strictly speaking this is a wild pointer - I've always called them dangling pointers, regardless of whether they are wild or dangling, and it's a hard habit to break. I'll fix it.